# Manage favorites in a notebook that can be published to PDF

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

Is there any chance to get a feature to create and manage online notebooks from favorite answers, and then publish them to pdf?

I mean create a notebook so it can hold favorite posts as pages and can be edited. Sometimes I see an answer, but it's not clear to me. I need to edit it for myself and save it. Sometimes I need many solutions and already answered questions for a project, so we can build a document for our problems, and even share it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting idea, but I think it's too far beyond the scope of the sites to provide such a feature.

You could download the latest [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) or [use the API](https://stackapps.com/) to mash up your own content like you're suggesting, maybe integrate it into a website of your own.